# Is there a way in Blazor to reverse map wasm-function(#) back to the c# method?

Tags: webassembly, blazor

I am running a Blazor page on Chrome and I see from the Chrome profiler that it is spending a lot of time in  the code wasm-function(633).  Is there any way for me to tell what c# code this corresponds to?

I want to improve the performance of the page and it would help to know what is causing the slow performance before changing any code.

I know that Blazor performance is not good compared to javascript etc., but I also have seen with limited experiments that some C# techniques perform better than others.  I was just looking for a data-driven way to find where my slow points are.

Comment: IDK if it helps, but you can write messages to JS comsole `Console.Writeline("hi")`. Maybe you can write your own profiler and flush results to console.

Comment: @dani Herrera. I think that you are right at this point. Console output seems to my best bet.

Comment: If it is a solution for you, I can try to elaborate and post it as solution in order to help other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `WasmEmitSymbolMap` property which allows to generates a `dotnet.js.symbols` file during compilation where you will find C# method to which `wasm-function(633)` corresponds to.

Another way is to use `WasmNativeStrip` property. By setting it false you will have C# method names not stripped. Please note that it can be only used in AOT compiled mode and it will increase dotnet.wasm size significantly.

[image]

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <WasmEmitSymbolMap>true</WasmEmitSymbolMap>
  <WasmNativeStrip>false</WasmNativeStrip>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can find full list of properties here - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/mono/wasm/build/WasmApp.targets

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73651974

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I think that it is not possible, yet, to trace wasm function calls back to c# code.  Blazor uses the Mono runtime which has been compiled to wasm. The wasm functions are really mono runtime code not my C# code.

My c# code is compiled to Intermediate Language (IL) which runs inside mono. I probably need to looks for a future Blazor profiler or a mono profiler that can compile to wasm to get what I was looking for.